# Solution to find all the tweets according to search text

Tags: c#, twitter

I have one application which shows all tweets according to search text in C#.
But while using Search API it only shows some limited number of tweets.
I use this 
"http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=Query&rpp=100"
What is the solution to find all the tweets according to search text?

Comment: this is not actually a C# question, it's a question regarding the Twitter API

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter search only goes back 5 - 7 days, or 1,500 tweets, whichever comes first. The search API is the same. Any tweets beyond that are not available through any known method. Twitter has them, but there is no way to get them. If you know in advance that you will want all tweets for some keywords or from some users, you need to use the streaming API to collect them in advance and save them in a database. Then you can search your database any time in the future to get all the tweets you have already saved.

To get all 1500 tweets, what you may need to do is set the `page` parameter on the API request. For example, right now, your request is only showing the 100 first (most recent) tweets, so to display the tweets from 100-200, you would do this:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=Query&rpp=100&page=2
```

And to get 200-300 of the tweets, you just increment the page number, up to a maximum of about 15 pages.